# Как правильно наложить z-index на слои формы?

Tags: html, css, css3

Мне нужна ваша помощь. Не могу разобраться с наложением z-index на слои. В коде у меня вёрстка средней формы авторизации. Мне нужно, чтобы текст в label (Email and Password) имел приоритетный индекс и был сверху общего фона всей формы, и при нажатии в любом месте input (в том числе на сам текст) label уходил наверх. Проблема в том, что без установленного фона общей формы (.form) всё отлично работает. Но мне необходимо залить фон общей формы (.form) белым цветом. Как только я заливаю его цветом, то текст label пропадает. Я устанавливаю label z-index 1, у меня текст накладывается поверх всей формы, но при нажатии на этот текст поле input не фокусируется. Буду очень рад помощи.

Код html:

```
        <div class="form__main">
            <form class="form">

                <h1 class="form__title">Вход в аккаунт</h1>
         
                <div class="form__group">
                    <input class="form__input" type="email" placeholder=" ">
                    <label class="form__label">Email</label>
                </div>

                <div class="form__group">
                    <input class="form__input" type="password" placeholder=" ">
                    <label class="form__label">Пароль</label>
                </div>

                <a href="#"><div class="form__button">Войти</div></a>
                <p class="form__other"><a href="registration.html">Регистрация</a></p> 
            </form>
        </div>
```

Код CSS:

```
.form__main {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 700px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.form {
    width: 400px;
    margin-top: -30px;
    padding: 32px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 16px #ccc;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 1;
}
.form__input,
.form__button {
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
}
.form__button {
    text-align: center;
}
.form__title {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 0 32px 0;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.form__group {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 32px;
}
.form__label {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    color: #9e9e9e;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
.form__input {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 0 10px 0;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    background-color: transparent;
    outline: none;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
.form__input:focus {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #5a2e83;
}
.form__button {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #5a2e83;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
.form a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.form__other {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.form__other a:hover {
    color: #9983d3;
}
.form__button:focus,
.form__button:hover {
    background-color: #9983d3;
}
.form__input:focus ~ .form__label,
.form__input:not(:placeholder-shown) ~ .form__label {
    top: -18px;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #e0e0e0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я надеюсь я правильно понял задачу.
Решение:

```css
.form__main {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 700px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.form {
    width: 400px;
    margin-top: -30px;
    padding: 32px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 16px #ccc;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 1;
}
.form__input,
.form__button {
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
}
.form__button {
    text-align: center;
}
.form__title {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 0 32px 0;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.form__group {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 32px;
}
.form__label {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    color: #9e9e9e;
    transition: 0.3s;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.form__input {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 0 10px 0;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    background-color: transparent;
    outline: none;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
.form__input:focus {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #5a2e83;
}
.form__button {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #5a2e83;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
.form a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.form__other {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.form__other a:hover {
    color: #9983d3;
}
.form__button:focus,
.form__button:hover {
    background-color: #9983d3;
}
.form__input:focus ~ .form__label,
.form__input:not(:placeholder-shown) ~ .form__label {
    top: -18px;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #e0e0e0;
}
```

```html
<div class="form__main">
            <form class="form">

                <h1 class="form__title">Вход в аккаунт</h1>
         
                <div class="form__group">
                    <input class="form__input" type="email" placeholder=" ">
                    <label class="form__label">Email</label>
                </div>

                <div class="form__group">
                    <input class="form__input" type="password" placeholder=" ">
                    <label class="form__label">Пароль</label>
                </div>

                <a href="#"><div class="form__button">Войти</div></a>
                <p class="form__other"><a href="registration.html">Регистрация</a></p> 
            </form>
        </div>
```

Я добавил в `.form__label` строку `pointer-events: none`
Таким образом мы скрываем наш label от мыши. Его всё так же видно, но кликаем мы по сути сразу же на input игнорируя label.